# Hadoop Streaming job failure "Python"

Tags: python, hadoop, cloudera, hadoop-streaming

Currenly I set up 11-nodes Hadoop cluster (CDH5) all services are up and running pretty well on both Resource Manager and all other nodes.
I was testing the cluster with word count program to make sure it works fine.

At the beginning, I got a permission denied error as it can't run mapper.py, some one suggested to move mapper.py and reducer.py to /tmp where everyone has execute permission. Looks like I don't get the permission denied Error anymore, but this error as shown shows up all the time.

Any clue or suggestions what I should do to go through this, I followed the logs nothing different than this Error message

```
[hduser@hdmachine1 ~]$ /usr/lib/hadoop/bin/hadoop jar /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-streaming-2.3.0-cdh5.1.0.jar -files /tmp/mapper.py,/tmp/reducer.py -mapper /tmp/mapper.py -reducer /tmp/reducer.py -input gutenberg/5000.txt.utf-8 -output output2
packageJobJar: [] [/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-streaming-2.3.0-cdh5.1.0.jar] /tmp/streamjob4274949694929495276.jar tmpDir=null
14/08/26 22:58:43 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at hdmachine1.example.com/128.243.29.224:8032
14/08/26 22:58:43 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at hdmachine1.example.com/128.243.29.224:8032
14/08/26 22:58:44 INFO lzo.GPLNativeCodeLoader: Loaded native gpl library
14/08/26 22:58:44 INFO lzo.LzoCodec: Successfully loaded & initialized native-lzo library [hadoop-lzo rev 8e266e052e423af592871e2dfe09d54c03f6a0e8]
14/08/26 22:58:44 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
14/08/26 22:58:44 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:2
14/08/26 22:58:44 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1409004459008_0015
14/08/26 22:58:45 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1409004459008_0015
14/08/26 22:58:45 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://hdmachine1.example.com:8088/proxy/application_1409004459008_0015/
14/08/26 22:58:45 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1409004459008_0015
14/08/26 22:58:49 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1409004459008_0015 running in uber mode : false
14/08/26 22:58:49 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
14/08/26 22:58:53 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1409004459008_0015_m_000001_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:75)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:426)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:342)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:167)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1554)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:106)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:75)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.configure(MapRunner.java:38)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:106)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: configuration exception
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:222)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.configure(PipeMapper.java:66)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/tmp/mapper.py": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:209)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:186)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1028)
    ... 24 more

14/08/26 22:58:53 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1409004459008_0015_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:75)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:426)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:342)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:167)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1554)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:106)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:75)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.configure(MapRunner.java:38)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:106)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: configuration exception
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:222)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.configure(PipeMapper.java:66)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/tmp/mapper.py": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:209)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:186)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1028)
    ... 24 more

14/08/26 22:58:56 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1409004459008_0015_m_000000_1, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:75)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:426)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:342)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:167)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1554)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:106)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:75)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.configure(MapRunner.java:38)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:106)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: configuration exception
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:222)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.configure(PipeMapper.java:66)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/tmp/mapper.py": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:209)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:186)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1028)
    ... 24 more

14/08/26 22:58:56 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1409004459008_0015_m_000001_1, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:75)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:426)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:342)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:167)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1554)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:106)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:75)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.configure(MapRunner.java:38)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:106)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: configuration exception
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:222)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.configure(PipeMapper.java:66)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/tmp/mapper.py": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:209)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:186)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1028)
    ... 24 more

14/08/26 22:58:59 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1409004459008_0015_m_000000_2, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:75)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:426)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:342)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:167)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1554)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:106)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:75)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.configure(MapRunner.java:38)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:106)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: configuration exception
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:222)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.configure(PipeMapper.java:66)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/tmp/mapper.py": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:209)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:186)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1028)
    ... 24 more

14/08/26 22:59:00 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1409004459008_0015_m_000001_2, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:75)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:426)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:342)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:167)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1554)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:106)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:75)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.configure(MapRunner.java:38)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:106)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: configuration exception
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:222)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.configure(PipeMapper.java:66)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/tmp/mapper.py": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:209)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:186)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1028)
    ... 24 more

14/08/26 22:59:05 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 100%
14/08/26 22:59:05 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1409004459008_0015 failed with state FAILED due to: Task failed task_1409004459008_0015_m_000000
Job failed as tasks failed. failedMaps:1 failedReduces:0

14/08/26 22:59:05 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 14
    Job Counters 
        Failed map tasks=7
        Killed map tasks=1
        Launched map tasks=8
        Other local map tasks=6
        Data-local map tasks=1
        Rack-local map tasks=1
        Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=15989
        Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=0
        Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=15989
        Total vcore-seconds taken by all map tasks=15989
        Total megabyte-seconds taken by all map tasks=16372736
    Map-Reduce Framework
        CPU time spent (ms)=0
        Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=0
        Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=0
14/08/26 22:59:05 ERROR streaming.StreamJob: Job not Successful!
Streaming Command Failed!
```

Answer (score 0):

The "No such file or directory" errors suggest that `/tmp/mapper.py` doesn't exist. Since the file is in `/tmp` it could have been deleted by a temp cleaning cron job, maybe by rebooting the system, or someone doing `rm /tmp/*`.

Comment: This is the weird thing, it is really there and I ran it manually and it worked.
using cat file.txt | /tmp/mapper.pu | sort | /tmp/reducer.py

I am getting crazy!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
-file /tmp/mapper.py -file /tmp/reducer.py
```

To ship files. Arg **-files** might be looking at hdfs